# Make phone beep using sl4a

Tags: python, sl4a

I'm writing a sort of "Wi-Fi Geiger Counter" app using sl4a on qpython (I know) that repeatedly:
1. scans for networks until it finds the one you specify (the amount of time that takes has something to do with how close you are to the AP)
2. Beeps with a frequency relative to the "level" data of the returned network.

The first part is simple enough, and I've already gotten it working with a simple warmer-colder app.  In all my searching, though, I have yet to find a way to make sl4a beep (except for Tasker, which I don't know how to use, or even if it's installed or not - the example QPython provides doesn't appear to do anything).  Is there another way? A function I haven't found?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not exactly sure how SL4A translates to QPython, in traditional SL4A you have two options.

One is to use the Media Facade if you have a sound file you want to play, which you can load and play immediately with

```
mediaPlay(
 String url: url of media resource,
 String tag[optional, default default]: string identifying resource,
 Boolean play[optional, default true]: start playing immediately)
```

eg., `sl4a.mediaPlay('path/to.file.mp3', 'beep', True)`

Alternatively, you can generate phone keypad tones using

```
generateDtmfTones(
 String phoneNumber,
 Integer toneDuration[optional, default 100]: duration of each tone in          
milliseconds)
```

eg., `sl4a.generateDtmfTones('0', 100)`

So you could head into your standard phone app, press numbers until you find one you'd like as the beep, use just that number as the "phone number" (such as above, where I just used `'0'`), and perhaps modify the `toneDuration` based on how hot or cold the person is (eg., hotter means smaller `toneDuration` and smaller `time.sleep(x)` between playing the tones)